# Should "come to know" be used with "about"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, usage, complements

Can it be used like "that's how I came to know about them"? E.g., being introduced to the work of artists.

Comment: In your final sentence don't you mean "how I came to **know** about"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can 'know about something' and that remains a valid construction when used as the target of 'come to'  ('target' because I'm intentionally staying away from grammatical technical terms -- I'm not 100% how to accurately label the various bits here)

Answer (score 1):

*COME* with a marked infinitive (*to VERB*) means broadly "to arrive at" the state or completed action denoted by *VERB*, can be employed with *COME* in any non-passive form or construction, and *VERB* will take its ordinary complements:

> Macbeth **comes**<sup>present</sup> to realize the emptiness of power.
>
> It was through working with Frank that she **came**<sup>past</sup> to learn about the Stellingas rebellion.
>
> Eventually you **will come**<sup>modal+infinitive</sup> to rely on her judgment.
>
> John **is coming**<sup>progressive</sup> to think less of his colleagues.
>
> I **have come**<sup>perfect</sup> to wonder at Brian's ability.
>
> **Coming**<sup>gerund</sup> to be who one really is is a long, slow process for many people.

Ordinarily, however, *COME* will not be cast as a marked infinitive; that would present two adjacent marked infinitives, which feels awkward to most people:

> If you make the effort **to come**<sup>marked infinitive</sup> to know him you will discover why we put up with his erratic temper.